# Simple Local Avatar Plugin

Tags: images, author, avatar, gravatar

I think that Im very close to achieve my goal..
I have this function on my themes but I need a help to find the right way to call simple local avatar function so it will show the local avatar image from simple local avatar pugin instead wordpress gravatar?

```
$first_img = get_avatar( $post->post_author );
```

Is there anyone can help?

```
function get_post_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = get_avatar( $post->post_author );
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

Comment: You are starting and stopping output buffering with nothing in between, which is pointless, but _in what context_ do you want to "call" the function? Are you trying to override the default avatar system?

Comment: The actual codes is below.. `function get_post_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
   $img_dir = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    $first_img = $img_dir . '/images/post-default.jpg';
  }
  return $first_img;`

Comment: That is what you have already posted in the question. How does that help and how does that answer my question?

Answer (score 1):

The [`get_avatar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) function is pluggable, meaning that you can define a function of your own having that name and completely overwrite the default function.

If you look at the source for the "Simple Local Avatars" plugin, [that is exactly what it has done](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/simple-local-avatars/trunk/simple-local-avatars.php#L546). `get_avatar` in your code should be using the function defined by "Simple Local Avatars".

"Simple Local Avatars" provides a simplified function, [`get_simple_local_avatar`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/simple-local-avatars/trunk/simple-local-avatars.php#L522), that you can use instead if you want.